# Why a pointer cannot store address of another pointer?

Tags: visual-c++, pointers

I have a pointer as follows:

```
int val2 = 90;

int *p = &val2;
```

Then, I do:

```
int *pp = &p; // Line 3
```

The `Line 3` is illegal. I know it should have written `int **pp = &p`, but I dont understand why. Is that the address of a normal variable different with the address of a pointer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int *pp` defines `pp` as a pointer to an `int`, but you're trying to initialize it with the address of a pointer to an `int` instead of the address of an `int`. Since "address of an int" and "address of a pointer to an int" don't have the same type, the compiler won't let you do this (at least without a cast, though you almost certainly *don't* want to do that).

Yes, the two types of pointers are *probably* the same size, so the CPU could move the data from one location to another without any real problem. The compiler, however, does type checking to help keep you from shooting yourself in the foot, and that's what it's doing here. It'll let you do what you're asking with the cast mentioned above, but since what you're doing makes little or no sense, you need to use a cast if you really insist on doing it.

Answer (score 2):

For a [static type checker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Static_typing) yes. From an implementation point of view no.

Since type checking must ensure that what you assign and pass around is correct with respect to how you declared it, it must reject

```
int *pp = &p;
```

because you are declaring `pp` as a pointer to int while trying to store there a pointer to pointer to int. Even if there is no difference between a pointer to something or to something else there is difference for the type checked if you declared it as a specific type.

Answer (score 1):

On the vast majority of platforms, all pointers are the same thing in memory: the address of somewhere else in memory. The issue is mostly a matter of trying to be type-safe so the computer can enforce correct usage.

You can always typecast between the different pointer types if it is necessary to store them as the wrong type.

Comment: Ignoring the compiler is a recipe for problems. Cast with care, not just to make the code compile.

Comment: Pointers *may* all be basically the same thing. On many implementations they are, but that's not necessarily the case -- there are also implementations where pointers to different types have different representations.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a pointer to an integer, so the compiler expects you to assign the address of an integer. Instead, you're assigning the address of a pointer, not an integer. In order for the compiler to know where to look for the int, you have to add the second asterisk, to tell the compiler that pp points to a memory adress, that in turn points to an int.